# While downloading how to handle iOS app crash after sleep?

Tags: ios, swift, urlsession

I download file in a table cell in ComicListViewcontroller, when I popViewController, and then get to ComicListViewcontroller, and then popViewController back again to ComicViewcontroller. If it sleeps, the app will crash when I go to home

```
func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, downloadTask: URLSessionDownloadTask, didWriteData bytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesWritten: Int64, totalBytesExpectedToWrite: Int64) {

        PublicClass.isFinishDownloading = false

        if let downloadUrl = downloadTask.originalRequest?.url?.absoluteString,
            let downloader = PublicClass.downloadFileLink[downloadUrl] {

            downloader.progress = Float(totalBytesWritten) / Float(totalBytesExpectedToWrite)

            self.totalItems = "\(PublicClass.downloadInProcess.count) Items"
            self.taskdownload = downloadTask

            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                print(downloader.progress)
                if(String(format: "%.1f%%", downloader.progress * 100) == "100.0%"){
                    print(String(format: "%.1f%%", downloader.progress * 100))
                    self.presenter.getComicList()
                    self.root.tableView.reloadData()
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

> 2019-07-12 10:02:55.617104+0700 Sariputta[2186:66954]
>   -[Sariputta.ComicListViewController originalRequest]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fe184599f30 2019-07-12
>   10:02:55.630284+0700 Sariputta[2186:66954]  Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[Sariputta.ComicListViewController originalRequest]: unrecognized
>   selector sent to instance 0x7fe184599f30'  First throw call stack: (
>     0   CoreFoundation                      0x000000011058e1bb
>   **exceptionPreprocess + 331   1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x000000010f6b0735 objc_exception_throw + 48    2   CoreFoundation
>
>   0x00000001105acf44 -[NSObject(NSObject) doesNotRecognizeSelector:] +
>   132   3   UIKitCore                           0x0000000118b27b4a
>   -[UIResponder doesNotRecognizeSelector:] + 287    4   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000110592ed6 ___forwarding_** + 1446  5   CoreFoundation
>   0x0000000110594da8 _CF_forwarding_prep_0 + 120    6   Sariputta
>   0x000000010b34cbf9
>   $S9Sariputta23ComicListViewControllerC10urlSession_12downloadTask12didWriteData17totalBytesWritten0mn10ExpectedToK0ySo12NSURLSessionC_So0r8DownloadI0Cs5Int64VA2NtF
>   + 233     7   Sariputta                           0x000000010b34d8b9 $S9Sariputta23ComicListViewControllerC10urlSession_12downloadTask12didWriteData17totalBytesWritten0mn10ExpectedToK0ySo12NSURLSessionC_So0r8DownloadI0Cs5Int64VA2NtFTo
>   + 105     8   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001104cdbac **CFNOTIFICATIONCENTER_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER** + 12  9   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001104cd02f
>   _CFXRegistrationPost + 447    10  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001104ccd71 **_CFXNotificationPost_block_invoke + 225    11 
>   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001105b3ae2
>   -[_CFXNotificationRegistrar find:object:observer:enumerator:] + 1826  12  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001104cc694
>   _CFXNotificationPost + 964    13  Foundation                          0x000000010e0b6589 -[NSNotificationCenter
>   postNotificationName:object:userInfo:] + 66   14  UIKitCore
>
>   0x0000000118b129cc -[UIApplication _sendWillEnterForegroundCallbacks]
>   + 136     15  UIKitCore                           0x0000000118317159 -[__UICanvasLifecycleMonitor_Compatability activateEventsOnly:withContext:completion:] + 2742    16  UIKitCore
>
>   0x0000000118314cb5 __82-[_UIApplicationCanvas
>   _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke
>   + 795     17  UIKitCore                           0x000000011831495f -[_UIApplicationCanvas _transitionLifecycleStateWithTransitionContext:completion:] + 435     18  UIKitCore                           0x0000000118319a90
>   __125-[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]_block_invoke
>   + 584     19  UIKitCore                           0x000000011831a80e _performActionsWithDelayForTransitionContext + 100   20  UIKitCore                           0x00000001183197ef -[_UICanvasLifecycleSettingsDiffAction
>   performActionsForCanvas:withUpdatedScene:settingsDiff:fromSettings:transitionContext:]
>   + 221     21  UIKitCore                           0x000000011831e93a -[_UICanvas scene:didUpdateWithDiff:transitionContext:completion:] + 392     22  UIKitCore                           0x000000011869b1f5
>   -[UIApplicationSceneClientAgent scene:handleEvent:withCompletion:] + 502  23  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011b876fdb
>   __80-[FBSSceneImpl updater:didUpdateSettings:withDiff:transitionContext:completion:]_block_invoke.359
>   + 213     24  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001119de602 _dispatch_client_callout + 8     25  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001119e1b78 _dispatch_block_invoke_direct + 301  26 
>   FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011b8b5ba8
>   __FBSSERIALQUEUE_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK** + 30     27  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011b8b5860
>   -[FBSSerialQueue _performNext] + 457  28  FrontBoardServices                  0x000000011b8b5e40 -[FBSSerialQueue _performNextFromRunLoopSource] +
>   45    29  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001104f3721
>   **CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION** + 17   30  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001104f2f93
>   __CFRunLoopDoSources0 + 243   31  CoreFoundation                      0x00000001104ed63f __CFRunLoopRun + 1263    32  CoreFoundation
>   0x00000001104ece11 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 625     33  GraphicsServices
>   0x000000011621d1dd GSEventRunModal + 62   34  UIKitCore
>   0x0000000118af981d UIApplicationMain + 140    35  Sariputta
>   0x000000010b47e3e7 main + 71  36  libdyld.dylib
>   0x0000000111a54575 start + 1  37  ???
>   0x0000000000000001 0x0 + 1 ) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with
>   uncaught exception of type NSException

Comment: Somewhere you are attempting to access `originalRequest` on an instance of `ComicListViewController` - This view controller doesn't have that property or function.

Comment: Why it access it? Meanwhile, it is still in ComicViewController

Comment: I don't know - It is your code - You need to look at the line that the stack trace indicates has the problem

Comment: It does access it and when I po it says:rror: Execution was interrupted, reason: internal ObjC exception breakpoint(-5)..
The process has been returned to the state before expression evaluation.

Answer (score 0):

I have known the answer, in ComicListViewController viewDidLoad()

```
if PublicClass.isDownloading == true {
            NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(urlSession(_:downloadTask:didWriteData:totalBytesWritten:totalBytesExpectedToWrite:)), name: UIApplication.willEnterForegroundNotification, object: nil)
            UIApplication.shared.isIdleTimerDisabled = true
        }
```

If I delete that code it doesn't crash, but I need that code to continue download file when get into it.